# SVN Update without changing my local files

Tags: svn

I made some refactoring on my project, so after trying to commit it I get an error: `"The directory is out of date"`. So I need to update my project. But how I can make `update` ignoring ALL upcoming files and changes? I really don't want to update any of my file or to download old files which I deleted in current revision.

(once I updated, so after updating all my refactored files overwritten by older versions(!!!) and I lost new version)

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what updating does... It is _supposed_ to modify your local files with changes from the server.  For files which you also have local changes, you'd use a merge tool to reconcile the differences.

Comment: update should merge all the files - then you need to remove any conflicts

Comment: commit any file you have deleted that will deletes in repository also..

Comment: @David . Ok, so I try to use merge tool. But what about files which I don't have locally? I don't want to download them.

Comment: @MyTitle: Yes you do.  Otherwise you won't have the correct source code.  After an update you should have the _complete_ source code from trunk plus your local changes.  Then you'd validate that your changes still work in the current codebase before committing them.  If the files you don't have are ones which you deleted as part of your changes then the SVN merge should be smart enough to notice that.  If not, just delete them again.  (Welcome to the pain of merges for large changes.  Continuous integration and continuous delivery are meant to address this.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you update your files you *will* change them. What you could do is mark them as merged and then commit, I think it would work, it's sort of like an "Override and commit", but I advise to do that carefully

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not possible. If have local changes in file "a" and the update brings a modified version of that file a, svn will try to merge the modifications. If not possible, it keeps your local file and you will have to merge them manually. However, you can checkout the head into a separate directory and merge all the modifications manually (including deleted/added files), but that would break down the whole concept of version control.

Answer (score 0):

See the dedit below.

@khachik: Well, what is "not possible" happened to me just now. I worked 5 hours on a MS Word document. The update before commiting "Restored" the document to the base revision (of Tuesday). No attempt to merge. No backup.

Edit: oops, not true. I renamed the file yesterday evening and continued working on it in the night. Obviously, the delete part of the svn rename was not successful leading to the restore. I now have both versions :-))